# Write a cell or a row with csvwriter in python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv

I want to export my list of results into a .xls file but the result is not as expected.

My code is:

```
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".xls")

if file:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel')
    for ele in arg:
        lista = list(ele)
        csvWriter.writerow(lista)

    file.close()
```

The content of my list `lista` is:

```
['ele1', 'ele2', '1215.0', '1.9', '1.37', '"ele3"']
```

But the result in the excel file is the content of the list in the first column and not 6 columns, one for each element of my list.

I want to place all the elements in different columns instead of different rows.

Comment: What is in the `arg`? I think you need to move the `writerow` outside the for loop, and use `lista.append(ele)`.

Comment: Did it not work if you did writerow(ele)?

Comment: 'arg' is a list of lists, so 'ele' is a list. Thanks

Comment: Finally I use pandas to solve this problem:     df = pd.DataFrame(arg)
    df.to_excel(file.name, header=False, index=False)

Answer (score 1):

This will put the list in a single row:

```
arg=['ele1', 'ele2', '1215.0', '1.9', '1.37', '"ele3"']
import csv

with open("test.csv", 'w') as mfile:
    writer = csv.writer(mfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(arg)
```

In the code above the csv writer is being called for each element separately and that's why its putting in in the same column or different rows.

Answer (score 0):

csv format is a **text** format. It consists of fields separated from each other with a delimiter character (by default the comma (`,`) hence the name), and optionnally enclosed in quotation marks (default double quote `"`). But it is common to have different delimiters. For example when the comma is used for decimal number (in French 0.5 writes 0,5), it is common to use the semicolon (`;`) as delimiter. At import time, Excel should tell how it is going to load the csv file. If nothing happens, you must search in Excel parameters, or directly in OS language setting what character is expected as the delimiter. Then you declare it in the csv writer, for example:

```
csvWriter = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel', delimiter = ";')
```

Without knowing more or the csv file content and the configuration of your systeme, I cannot say more...